# How to avoid using a lot of `document.createElement` to display JSON data.

Tags: javascript, json

After making an API call and getting the requested data back, I'm trying to display it on the page. However, I know of just two methods to doing this in vanilla JS: one is with `innerHTML` and just putting all the code in there, and the other is using multiple `object.createElement` calls.

Here's the portion of my code that does this. This function is called each time an API call is made and the response is loaded:

```
function buildLinks() {
    spin();
    /*  Checks if current user [passed as param] is currently live by matching userID's from 'streams' and 'users'
        For each user that's live, add a 'name' property to userID_stream with the name of the game being played. */
    userID_users.forEach(elem => {
        function checkIfLive(user) {
            for (let key of userID_streams) {
                if (key.user_id == user.id) {
                    if (key.name == null) {
                        userGame.textContent = "Not In Game."
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        userGame.textContent = "Game: " + key.name;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        const mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
        const imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
        const textDiv = document.createElement('div');
        const userLinkText = document.createElement('p');
        const userLinkUrl = document.createElement('a');
        const userImg = document.createElement('img');
        const userStatus = document.createElement('p');
        const userGame = document.createElement('p');

        userLinkUrl.href = `https://twitch.tv/${elem.login}`;
        userLinkUrl.textContent = `${elem.display_name}`;

        userImg.src = `${elem.profile_image_url}`;

        if (checkIfLive(elem)) {
            userStatus.textContent = 'Live';
            userStatus.classList.add('status_live');
        } else {
            userStatus.textContent = 'Offline';
            userStatus.classList.add('status_offline');
        }

        userLinkText.appendChild(userLinkUrl);
        imgDiv.appendChild(userImg);
        textDiv.appendChild(userLinkText);
        textDiv.appendChild(userStatus);
        textDiv.appendChild(userGame);

        userLinkText.classList.add('username');
        userStatus.classList.add('status');
        userGame.classList.add('game');
        mainDiv.classList.add('stream');
        imgDiv.classList.add('stream_img');
        textDiv.classList.add('stream_desc');

        mainDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
        mainDiv.appendChild(textDiv);
        content.appendChild(mainDiv);
    });
}
```

As you can see, it's got a lot of repetition and creating elements and then adding calsses and appending each created element into parent elements.

My question is, is there a better way to do this, using vanilla JS? And if so, how should I go about it?

Comment: You can try using a [HTML <template> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Answer (score 3):

You will just end up re-inventing the wheel, so just use some view library that helps (except jQuery, never use jQuery).

You might write something like this:

```js
const element = (name, ...args) => {
  const e = document.createElement(name);
  args.forEach(arg => {
    if (arg instanceof HTMLElement)
      e.appendChild(arg);
    else if (typeof arg == 'string')
      e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arg));
    else
      Object.entries(arg).forEach(([key, value]) => e.setAttribute(key, value));
  });
  return e;
};

console.log(
  element("div", { class: "main" },
    element("h1", "Title"),
    element("div", { class: "content" },
      element("span", "Text Here"),
      element("span", "Even More Text Here")
    )
  ).outerHTML
);
```